# error in for loop. android application

Tags: android, json, eclipse

i'm still new in this programming. I tried to assign the marker.get("title") to title array. there is no error mark somehow the apps crash if i run it. thanks for helping

EDIT there is no ** in the real code. i just want to point where the error.

```
@Override
  protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
      for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
          HashMap<String, String> marker = result.get(i);
          LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng")));
          PlaceName = marker.get("title");
          Address = marker.get("FullAddress");
          telno = marker.get("telno");
          addMarker(latlng, PlaceName, Address);

          **for (int x=0;x<=i;x++)
          {
              title[x]=marker.get("title");
          }**

      }
  }
}
```

logcat error

```
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994): Process: com.mha.katpenang, PID: 30994
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at com.mha.katpenang.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:252)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at com.mha.katpenang.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:805)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
11-21 10:16:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(30994):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

fixed : the title variable size need to be set on declaration.

Comment: could you post the error log?.

Comment: Is your title initialized? Please, at least post the error log (logcat) for the crash, or only the God can guess where exactly goes wrong.

Comment: Just to be clear, in logcat whenever there is a crash the log will fill with red text. Get that and post it here. It's a good habit to look at that text, as it'll describe the error in some way.

Comment: How have you defined the `title` ?

Comment: sorry for that, i already add it up but i can't post in picture format yet. not enough rep.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri if define = declare as variable, then i did it already.

Comment: Can you post it how? Did you use `String [] title = new String[whteverSize]` or something like that? ALso try to Log and see the vlaues you are getting in the hashmap. It might be that "ttile" does not exist, that's why giving null.

Comment: I forgot to set it size. now it's fixed and working just fine. thank you for helping @ShobhitPuri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how have you defined the array `title`. It should be something like:

```
String [] title = new String[whateverSize]; // with your chosen size
```

Hop it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put null check before doing any operation on getting value like you are doing

> ```
>       LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng")));
> ```

It's better if you it like:-

```
@Override
  protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
      if(result != null){
        for(int i=0; i<result.size();i++){
          HashMap<String, String> marker = result.get(i);

          LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lat")!=null ?
          marker.get("lat") : "0.0"), Double.parseDouble(marker.get("lng") !=null?
          marker.get("lng") :"0.0"));

          PlaceName = marker.get("title");
          Address = marker.get("FullAddress");
          telno = marker.get("telno");
          addMarker(latlng, PlaceName, Address);

          **for (int x=0;x<=i;x++)
          {
              title[x]=marker.get("title");
          }**

      }
   }

}
```